# Fetch distinct record from dataset/table using linq to dataset/datatable

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am fetching record from database and store a result in dataset.

My dataset like this

```
Sid Table userid par1 par2 par3
274 tbl1  43     0    0    0
232 tbl1  43     1    2    0
232 tbl1  43     1    2    1
232 tbl2  43     1    2    0
232 tbl2  43     1    2    1
```

I want to show all 6 column but distinct record.Distinct should be on  Sid, Table and userid.I want output like this

```
Sid Table userid par1 par2 par3
 274 tbl1  43     0    0    0
 232 tbl1  43     1    2    0
 232 tbl2  43     1    2    0
```

Does it possible through linq to dataset/datatable.
I am unable to get AsEnumerable method on dataset but getting on datatable.

Comment: Do you want to join two tables, Dataset.Tables[0] (for tbl1) and Dataset.Tables[1] (for tbl2) and then group by on Sid, Table and userid?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by dataset, I am reffering  to "I am unable to get AsEnumerable method on dataset but getting on datatable"

Comment: I showing result in gridview. I am using dataset as datasource for binding gridview.

Comment: And how are you trying to do this, please add that code also, where do you expecting "AsEnumerable method on dataset".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105084/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-jui-test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused with the question but is this want you want?

```
yourDatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.GroupBy(r => new { Sid = r.Field<int>("Sid"), userid = r.Field<int>("userid"), Table = r.Field<string>("Table") })
.Select(e => e.FirstOrDefault())
.Select(grp => new
{
    Sid = grp.Field<int>("Sid"),
    userid = grp.Field<int>("userid"),
    Table = grp.Field<string>("Table"),
    par1 = grp.Field<int>("par1"),
    par2 = grp.Field<int>("par2"),
    par3 = grp.Field<int>("par3")
});
```

Comment: Hi codingangel08,thanks for ur help.I worked for me.Insted of specifing column,can I take all column of datatable.Because my columns are dynamic.If it is present in datatable,take it.